Selecting elements from sublists (with removal) subject to constraints on the sublist choice
My problem is a little difficult to explain so I'll exhibit with a couple of examples.
Given the following nested list - {{5,13},{5,11},{23}} - imagine the sublists are urns with balls numbered with the integers in the given sublists. Thus urn 1 has two balls labelled 5 and 13 respectively. Urn 2 has balls labelled 5 and 11 respectively and Urn 3 has a single ball labelled 23.
First we select a ball from Urn 1 (say the ball labelled 5) and remove it and store this choice as {1,5} - i.e. the ball labelled 5 came from urn 1.
Now we select a ball from urn 2, say the one labelled with a 5 and we store this along with our earlier saved choice and we have the result {1,5} {2,5}.
Moving on - we select the single ball from urn 3 and our stored result becomes
{1,5} {2,5} {3,23}
We now move back to urn 1 and remove the ball labelled 13 and our stored result is now {1,5} {2,5} {3,23} {1,13}. We move next to urn 2 and remove the single remaining ball labelled 11 and store the final result {1,5} {2,5} {3,23} {1,13} {2,11}. Job done.
Now an example where this process cannot be completed.
Starting with {{5,5,11},{13},{23}}.
We get {1,5} as our initial result - then {1,5} {2,13} then {1,5} {2,13} {3,23}
then {1,5} {2,13} {3,23} {1,5} BUT we cannot continue because urns 2 and 3 are now empty, because we have to take the urns in order, and thus we are left with a ball in urn 1 we can't do anything with.
(* code would produce in the first case *)

{{5,13},{5,11},{23}} -> {1,5} {2,5} {3,23} {1,13} {2,11}

(* code would produce in the second case *)

{{5,5,11},{13},{23}} -> {}

Now a long time ago I brute forced this with some horrible code full of For loops and If statements that has since been lost to the great bit bucket in the sky. But I was hoping someone had a clever way of doing this process "Mathematica style" and also handling when to return a null result as in the second example.
Note that there can be different numbers of urns (sublists) and varied numbers of elements (balls) in these sublists - but the sublists (urns) are always ordered from left to right (urn 1 thru urn k) by the number of balls in them. I also do not need the intermediate results just the end product.
If nothing else I should learn something here in regard to using Mathematica. And ideas/help would be much appreciated.
EDIT:
I knew this was hard to explain - given I didn't give enough clarity:
Further example with 4 urns.
{{5,5,7},{11,23},{13,21},{11}}
Should give an output of:
{1,5} {2,11} {3,13} {4,11} {1,5} {2,23} {3,21} {1,7}
In other words - as long as you can append a sample to the end by not violating that an urn cannot be sampled twice in a row then you can carry on. In this example even though the 4th urn is empty after its initial sampling you can still carry on with the process.
Similarly - {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9}} can be completed to give:
{1,1} {2,5} {3,9} {1,2} {2,6} {1,3} {2,7} {1,4} {2,8}
My fault for not giving that info the first time.

For the second example would the output be {{1,5}, {2,13}, {3,23}, {1,5}} as you suggested or { }?

@syed It should be { } because the process cannot continue because you cannot have consecutive results from the same urn and thus an urn is left that is not empty. If you notice the first element of each result is different from the prior result.

If the only rule is you cannot have consecutive results from the same urn, then the urn with the most items is at most allowed to be 1 item more than the next longest urn, right? If it's more, then you will have more than one item left in the biggest urn on the last iteration, and therefore would have a consecutive urn number.

@ydd I think it is along the line that the longest urn cannot be one more than the sum of the other urns. If you look at my EDIT in the question at the end it is more complex than just one more than the next longest.

Update
After reading the updated conditions, I believe this is correct. An urn will only be sampled twice in a row, when it's the only urn left. In other words, the urn with maximal length must be at most 1 greater than the next longest urn:
newFunction[urnList_] := Module[{k,maxL, nextLongest},
  k = Length @ urnList;
  maxL = RankedMax[Length /@ urnList, 1];
  nextLongest = RankedMax[Length /@ urnList, 2];
  (*if the longest urn won't be sampled consecutively on the last \
draw*)
  If[maxL - nextLongest <= 1,
   
   (*use Check to return nothing if we can't get any more balls from \
a given urn*)
   Table[Check[{i, urnList[[i, j]]}, Nothing], {j, 1, maxL}, {i, k}] //
      Quiet // Flatten[#, 1] &,
   {}
   ]
  ]

And checking with the test cases:
urnList1 = {{5, 13}, {5, 11}, {23}};
urnList2 = {{5, 5, 11}, {13}, {23}};
urnList3 = {{5, 5, 7}, {11, 23}, {13, 21}, {11}};
urnList4 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9}};
urnLists = {urnList1, urnList2, urnList3, urnList4};

newFunction /@ urnLists // MatrixForm



Original Post
Here's how I am currently interpreting the question:
A collection of urns is valid if you can take urn numbers in the following consecutive scheme:
{{1,2,...,k},...,{1,2,...,n}}

where n ≤ k. This means that the first n urns must all have maximal length lMax, and the last k-n (which can be 0 when n==k) urns must have one minus this length lMax-1.
So to test for validity of an urn collection:
validUrnsQ[urnsList_List] := Module[{urnLengths, lMax},
  
  urnLengths = Length /@ urnsList;
  (*split up the lengths*)
  urnLengths = urnLengths // Split;
  (*delete duplicates of each split group*)
  urnLengths = DeleteDuplicates /@ urnLengths // Flatten;
  
  (*get max length*)
  lMax = Max@urnLengths;
  
  (*if a valid urn collection, should look like {lMax,
  lMax-1} or just {lMax} if they all have the same length*)
  urnLengths == {lMax, lMax - 1} || urnLengths == {lMax}
  ]

And then once we've tested validity, we can do the urn picking scheme:
urnSelection[urnsList_List] := Module[{k, n, minL, startPart},
  
  If[validUrnsQ[urnsList],
   
   (*number of urns*)
   k = Length@urnsList;
   (*number of urns with maximal length*)
   n = Length /@ urnsList // Split // First // Length;
   (*calculate minimum length of urns (always last urn if valid)*)
   minL = Length@Last@urnsList;
   (*take and transpose the part that consists of all urns*)
   startPart = Transpose[urnsList[[All, 1 ;; minL]]];
   (*thread with urn index*)
   startPart = Flatten[Thread[{Range[k], #}] & /@ startPart, 1];
   (*join the last part *)
    startPart~Join~Thread[{Range[n], urnsList[[1 ;; n, -1]]}]
   ,
   (*if invalid urn collection*)
   {}
   ]
  ]


So for example:
urnList1 = {{5, 13}, {5, 11}, {23}};
urnList2 = {{5, 5, 11}, {13}, {23}};

urnSelection[urnList1]
urnSelection[urnList2]

(*{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 23}, {1, 13}, {2, 11}}*)

(*{}*)


I posted this to the other answer - see my EDIT in the question. I wasn't clear enough initially - the process can carry on by cycling through other urns even though one or more are empty - the only rule that needs be followed is you can always append new results as long as it doesn't follow immediately from using the same urn. I shall look at your answer in more detail after dinner. Much appreciated.

Excellent. That newFunction is very succinct and works like a charm. I'm too mired in years of Fortran to think in a Mathematica style at times. Everything is loops and conditionals - the more the merrier at times. Your contribution is much appreciated.

One way to solve the problem of different length of the urns to not use Quiet is as follows:
UrnSelect[urnList_List] := Module[{k, maxL, nextLongest, urn, res},
  k = Length[urnList];
  urn = urnList;
  maxL = Max[Length /@ urn];
  nextLongest = If[k > 1, Sort[Length /@ urn, Greater][[2]], 0];
  res = {};
  If[maxL - nextLongest <= 1,
  res = Flatten[Table[
  If[Length[urn[[i]]] > 0, 
  With[{ball = {i, First[urn[[i]]]}}, urn[[i]] = Rest[urn[[i]]]; ball], Nothing],
  {j, 1, maxL}, {i, k}], 1]]; res];

  UrnSelect[{{5, 13}, {5, 11}, {23}}]

  UrnSelect[{{5, 5, 11}, {13}, {23}}]

  UrnSelect[{{5, 5, 7}, {11, 23}, {13, 21}, {11}}]

  UrnSelect[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9}}]


{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 23}, {1, 13}, {2, 11}}


{}


{{1, 5}, {2, 11}, {3, 13}, {4, 11}, {1, 5}, {2, 23}, {3, 21}, {1, 7}}


{{1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {1, 2}, {2, 6}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {1, 4}, {2, 8}}


Here is an example. You can declare a While loop that loops repeatedly over the urns until it hits an empty one. In each step, it chooses a ball from the not empty urn and transfers it to the result:
balls[urns0_] := Module[{urns = urns0, i = 1, res = {}, j},
  While[Length[urns[[i]]] > 0,
   j = RandomChoice[Range@Length@urns[[i]]];
   AppendTo[res, {i, urns[[i, j]]}];
   urns[[i]] = Delete[urns[[i]], j];
   i = 1 + Mod[i, Length[urns]];
   ];
  If[Length[Flatten[urns0]] == Length[res], res, {}]
  ]

Now with this:
balls[{{5, 13}, {5, 11}, {23}}]

{{1, 13}, {2, 5}, {3, 23}, {1, 5}, {2, 11}}

And:
balls[{{5, 5, 11}, {13}, {23}}]

{}

Addendum
For the new condition that we continue until a not empty urn other than the current one can be found, we need to change the While loop:
balls[urns0_] := Module[{urns = urns0, i = 1, res = {}, j},
  While[i0 = i; 
   While[Length[urns[[i]]] == 0 && (i = 1 + Mod[i, Length[urns]];) != 
      i0 , ++i]; urns[[i]] != {} ,
   j = RandomChoice[Range@Length@urns[[i]]];
   AppendTo[res, {i, urns[[i, j]]}];
   urns[[i]] = Delete[urns[[i]], j];
   i = 1 + Mod[i, Length[urns]];
   ];
  If[Length[Flatten[urns0]] == Length[res], res, {}]
  ]
balls[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9}}]

With this:
balls[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9}}]

{{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {1, 4}, {2, 8}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {1, 1}, {2, 
  6}}


@ Daniel Huber Yes that works nicely but see my EDIT in the question. I wasn't clear enough initially - the process can carry on by cycling through other urns even though one is empty - the only rule that needs be followed is you can always append new results as long as it doesn't follow immediately from the same urn.

Thanks for that - nice to see different ways of doing things - sometimes I feel that should be an official slogan - "Mathematica for doing things a myriad ways".

Here is an alternative approach using PadRight and MapIndexed:
func[u_] := Module[{pr = PadRight[u, Automatic, "x"], c},
  c = Catenate[
     MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, #] & /@ Transpose[pr]] /. {___, 
      "x"} :> Nothing;
  c /. {___, {1, _}, {1, _}, ___} :> {}
  ]

Testing
original = {{5, 13}, {5, 11}, {23}};
test0 = {{5, 5, 11}, {13}, {23}};
test1 = {{5, 5, 7}, {11, 23}, {13, 21}, {11}};
test2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9}};
func[original]
func[test0]
func[test1]
func[test2]

yields:
{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 23}, {1, 13}, {2, 11}}
{}
{{1, 5}, {2, 11}, {3, 13}, {4, 11}, {1, 5}, {2, 23}, {3, 21}, {1, 7}}
{{1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {1, 2}, {2, 6}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {1, 4}, {2, 
  8}}


+1 That's a very clever way to handle the issue of different urn lengths!

I read that you're having major surgery tomorrow. I hope everything goes well, mate. Blessings!

@E.Chan-López thank you: much appreciated.
